# Noticed some gaps/rot on the wood trim of my chimney need temp solution for next week and also long term solution, any suggestions?

Tags: water-damage, chimney

Noticed some gaps/rot on the wood trim of my chimney. Need temp solution for rain next week and also long term solution, any suggestions?

I posted this a couple weeks ago but managed to get my drone up finally to get better images. There's a badly designed cricket that seems to lead the water right into that rotted hole.

I have two questions:

1. I have some rain coming next week, what would be a good temporary solution just for next week? Caulking, big gap filler? temporary makeshift flashing?
2. What's the long term solution, replace the whole trim, a piece of it?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Short term a can of roofing tar should work, but gets all over your clothes/hands.  Messy stuff.  Slap it on the roof and chimney.  Long term, replace rotted wood or replace with vinyl/aluminum siding.

Comment: Yup, roofing tar or, you could use some silicon caulk for a week or two. Caulk would come off easier when you get back up to do a permanent repair.